# tamanho do passo em loop for MATLAB

Tags: for, matlab

Tenho o seguinte loop no MATLAB, gostaria de saber como faço para minha variável k ser incrementada de 0.15 em 0.15 até chegar a 10.

```
 for k=1:1:10
 %...
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O controle de loop funciona com

```
A= inicio:passo:final;
```

No seu caso

```
for x=0.15:0.15:10
...
```

Resolve o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, nesse seu caso o incremento (passo) deve ser de 0.15 e não 1 como sugeriu na exemplificação. Então faça o seguinte:

for k=1:0.15:10  % k = inicio:incremento/decremento:fim

```
  %...
```

end